# Cannot open precompiled header file: 'precheader.pch': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, cocos2d-x

I just set up a fresh cocos2d project using the `cocos new` cli. When I open the project, I am immediately greeted with several errors about files not being able to open the precompiled header. The files don't actually try to include these files though, so I'm guessing it's a CMake setting. Are these files supposed to be automatically generated?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. Sorry if this a duplicate post, but i've been trying to get this to work for the past 2 hours but with no success...

Comment: Do you really need precompiled headers?  Profile to see if the precompiled headers save you significant time on the builds.  Otherwise turn them off.  Your issue is just one of many reasons not to use precompiled headers.

Comment: I'd love to turn them off but I have no idea how to, I'm a complete beginner with CMake. Disabling them is easy when using visual studio's sln project structure, but I can't find a solution with cmake

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 has the command line "/Yu" to enable precompiled headers.  Check your options passed to the compiler.  You could also search the internet for "MSDN C++ visual studio command line precompiled headers off"

Comment: That only works when using visual studio project files though right? I don't have a "project settings" menu since I'm using cmake

Comment: I didn't say to use the project file.  I said passing command line switches to the compiler.  Big difference.  When using a makefile, you'll be passing command line switches to the compiler (such as the classic `-I` and `-c`).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate Visual Studio project files:

```
cd YourGame\proj.win32
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -A win32
```

Then open the generated solution file, it should compile without any error.